# Masonry ColumnWidth %

Tags: css, width, percentage, masonry

I am hoping someone can help me out. I've been going at it for quite some hours, but I can't seem to fix it (I am a rank $%#@! amateur). I've been trying to get masonry working with different width sizes. The sizes are in %. I am customizing a Wordpress theme, so I am dealing with a pre coded masonry file and pre coded css.

The css and html basically come down to this (if you need more code, please let me know):

```
.posts {
    overflow: visible !important; 
    position: relative;
}

.post-container {
    width: 50%
    padding: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.post-container .w2 {
    width: 100%
    padding: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

The html:

```
<div class="posts">
    <div class="post-container w2>Post</div>
    <div class="post-container>Post</div>
    <div class="post-container>Post</div>
</div>
```

The masonry:

```
//Masonry blocks
$blocks = $(".posts");

$blocks.imagesLoaded(function() {
    $blocks.masonry({
        itemSelector: '.post-container',
    });

    // Fade blocks in after images are ready (prevents jumping and re-rendering)
        $(".post-container").fadeIn();
    });

    $(document).ready( function() { setTimeout( function() { $blocks.masonry(); }, 500); });

    $(window).resize(function () {
        $blocks.masonry();
    });
```

So: the two 'post-container' won't slide together if the first post is a 'post-container .2'. If I post the two 'post-container' first however, and then the 'post-container .2' they do slide together.
From searching the interwebs, I gathered it has something to do with the masonry ColumnWidth. I tried many different options, but to no avail.  Setting ColumnWidth to '.post-container' wont do the trick at least. It seems the masonry always uses the 100% width if the first post is '.post-container .w2' despite all the following posts being 50% ('post-container').

What do I need to do so I can have different % widths, even if the first is 100%?

I hope I am not too unclear, but if I am, please tell me and I will try to explain it better.
Thanks for taking the time to read this.

Best,
Alan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If columnWidth is not set, Masonry will use the outer width of the first element.

This explains why each element was in new row, they all had 100% width.

It is convenient to use external CSS class to set size of the column. It is also important to set `box-sizing: border-box;` if your elements have paddings.

In the following demo I've set `columnWidth` option to 25% - you can adjust it in `.sizer` CSS class, if for example you will need to have 10 elements side by side - you have to set it to 10%. You can of course "connect" columns and have two elements with 50% widths set in CSS.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/Lob6mse1/2/

JavaScript:

```
$blocks = $(".posts");
$blocks.masonry({
    itemSelector: '.post-container',
    columnWidth: ".sizer"
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="posts">
    <div class="sizer"></div>
    <div class="post-container w2">Post</div>
    <div class="post-container">Post</div>
    <div class="post-container">Post</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.posts * {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}

.posts {
    position: relative;
}

.post-container {
    width: 50%;
    min-height: 100px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: #999;
}

.w2 {

    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #EEE;
}

.sizer {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 25%;
}
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks so much JackBauer. You are a great person! Your time and effort are much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

The correct way to refer to a div with multiple classes in CSS is:

```
.post-container.w2 {
    width: 100%
    padding: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

You have to delete the space between the first class and the second class. Otherwise you are referring to a class inside a class in the html. So:

```
<div class="posts">
    <div class="post-container>
        <div class="w2">
            Post
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="post-container>Post</div>
    <div class="post-container>Post</div>
</div>
```

I hope this resolves your problem

Comment: It did not solve the issue, but thank you very much for your input, Nick V. Much appreciated!